# Computing the derivative of $H(z)= \int_{e^z}^{\cos z} \ln(w^3) ~dw$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am stuck on this problem:

> Find the derivative of the function: $$H(z)= \int_{e^z}^{\cos z} \ln(w^3) ~dw.$$

Comment: Leibniz Integral rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: Would it help you if we rewrote your function as $$\int_1^{\cos z} \ln(w^3)\mathrm dw-\int_1^{e^z} \ln(w^3) ~dw$$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will use a (very) modified brute force approach.  Let $f(w)=\ln(w^3)$. The idea is to find an antiderivative $F(w)$ of $f(w)$. Then $H(z)=F(\cos z)-F(e^z)$. Once we have found $F(w)$, we will have an expression for $H(z)$, and differentiation should be easy.

But we don't need to *find* $F(w)$!  We have 
$$H(z)=F(\cos z)-F(e^z).$$
Differentiate, using the Chain Rule, and recalling that though we never calculated $F(w)$, we know that $F'(w)=f(w)$. We get
$$H'(z)=(-\sin z)f(\cos z)-(e^z)f(e^z).$$
But $f(w)=\ln(w^3)=3\ln w$. Thus 
$$H'(z)=(-\sin z)(3)(\ln(\cos z)) -(e^z)(3)(z).$$
The answer looks nicer if we write it  as $-3\left[\sin z\,\ln(\cos z)+ze^z\right]$.

**Comment:** In this case, finding $F(w)$, an antiderivative of $\ln(w^3)$, is easy, particularly if we notice that $\ln(w^3)=3\ln w$.  However, the technique we used works for "any" $f(w)$, even if we don't know an antiderivative of $f(w)$.

I went through the full *reasoning*, but one use the reasoning to obtain a general *formula*, and after that just use the formula.
Let $f(w)$, $a(z)$, and $b(z)$ be nice functions, and let
$$H(z)=\int_{a(z)}^{b(z)}f(w)\,dw.$$
Then 
$$H'(z)=b'(z)f(b(z))-a'(z)f(a(z)).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
If $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are differentiable and $f(u)$ is a continuous function between $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, then $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(u)~du = f(g(x))\cdot g'(x)-f(h(x))\cdot h'(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

By the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if $f(u)$ is continuous we have:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(u)\,du = f(x).$$
Using the Chain Rule, if $h(x)$ is any function, we have:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{h(x)} f(u)\,du = f(h(x))h'(x).$$

Using this and properties of the integral, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dz}H(z) &= \frac{d}{dz}\int_{e^z}^{\cos z} \ln(w^3)\,dw\\
&=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\int_{e^z}^1\ln(w^3)\,dw +\int_1^{\cos z}\ln(w^3)\,dw\right)\\
&=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\int_1^{\cos z}\ln(w^3)\,dw - \int_1^{e^z}\ln(w^3)\,dw\right)\\
&=\frac{d}{dz}\int_1^{\cos z}\ln(w^3)\,dw - \frac{d}{dz}\int_1^{e^z}\ln(w^3)\,dw\\
&= \ln(\cos^3(z))(\cos z)' - \ln((e^z)^3)(e^z)'\\
&= -3\sin z\ln(\cos z) - 3ze^z.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force approach:

1. Use change of variable: $x = w^3$
2. Use integration by parts on the resulting integral to integrate the function.
3. Find the derivative the usual way using chain rule/product rules etc.

Comment: For evaluating the integral, it might be slightly easier to observe that $\ln (w^3) = 3 \ln w$, although this approach still does not avoid integration by parts.